# Automatic ID in flutter firebase

Tags: flutter, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I'm making a app in flutter it's about an OTP login it's basic but, how can I make an automatic ID registration in the firebase?

So, this is the code

```
  void saveUserDataToFirebase({
    required BuildContext context,
    required UserModel userModel,
    required File profilePic,
    required Function onSuccess,
  }) async {
    _isLoading = true;
    notifyListeners();
    try {
      //Subir imagen a firebase storage
      await storeFileToStorage("profilePic/$_uid", profilePic).then((value) {
        userModel.profilePic = value;
        userModel.createdAt = DateTime.now().microsecondsSinceEpoch.toString();
        userModel.phoneNumber = _firebaseAuth.currentUser!.phoneNumber!;
        userModel.uid = _firebaseAuth.currentUser!.phoneNumber!;
      });
      _userModel = userModel;
      //SUBIR A LA BASE DE DATOS
      await _firebaseFirestore
          .collection("mecanicos")
          .doc(_uid)
          .set(userModel.toMap())
          .then((value) {
        onSuccess();
        _isLoading = false;
        notifyListeners();
      });
    } on FirebaseAuthException catch (e) {
      showSnackBar(context, e.message.toString());
      _isLoading = false;
      notifyListeners();
    }
```

When it's in try its asing the "Id" like "_uid " for upload the fotoright? but I put the userModel.uid with the pone number, and when I'm sending the data to firebase I use the "_uid" but for some reason the Id that is appear in the firestore database its the phone nomber and not the _uId

Here can see how the title of the pics its the _uid
[image]

And in the collection in firestore the ID is the phone number
[image]

Comment: This seems the reason: `userModel.uid = _firebaseAuth.currentUser!.phoneNumber!;`. You probably want that to be `userModel.uid = _firebaseAuth.currentUser!.uid;`

Comment: yes, that's what i thought

When I'm debuggin its shows an error. but the app works well, you can se how I do in the answer, its similar to your answer, thanks bro

Answer (score 0):

I make this solution for now, it's something like this:

```
await storeFileToStorage("profilePic/$_uid", profilePic).then((value) {
        userModel.profilePic = value;
        userModel.createdAt = DateTime.now().microsecondsSinceEpoch.toString();
        userModel.phoneNumber = _firebaseAuth.currentUser!.phoneNumber!;
        userModel.uid = _firebaseAuth.currentUser!.uid.toString();
      });
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).